# My cron job doesn't cp my file

Tags: bash, unix, cron

I have a bash script who is use to backup my apache directories.
When I'm root and I excecute my script he work fine (my directory is copied).
But when I create a cron, my script is launched but the backup is not moved... Why ?

My cron job:
0 12 * * * /home/dim/backup/backup.sh -mail

My script:

```
$TMP_NAME="backup"     
mv -f $TMP_NAME.tar.gz /test/
```

The directory "test" and "backup" have -r 777 rights

Thanks you !!

Comment: You probably need to give full path of your `.tar.gz` file.

Comment: The problem was the full path.. Thanks you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The working directory of a script executed by cron is the file system root -> `/`. You need to use the full path to the file:

```
$TMP_NAME="/full/path/to/backup"     
mv -f $TMP_NAME.tar.gz /test/
```